# LDAP not showing secondary groups

Tags: openldap

Currently, I have a LDAP server (running ClearOS if that makes any difference) containing a database of users.

So, I went and setup LDAP on a couple of my debian VMs, using libpam-ldapd and I discovered this odd problem.

My group/user mapping would show up when running

```
getent group
```

but the secondary groups would not show up when running

```
id
```

.

Here is my /etc/nslcd.conf

```
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslcd configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldaps://10.3.0.1

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base dc=pnet,dc=sandyd,dc=me

# The LDAP protocol version to use.
#ldap_version 3

# The DN to bind with for normal lookups.
binddn cn=manager,ou=internal,dc=pnet,dc=sandyd,dc=me
bindpw password

# The DN used for password modifications by root.
#rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

# SSL options
ssl on
tls_reqcert never

# The search scope.
#scope sub

#filter group (&(objectClass=group)(gidNumber=*))
map group uniqueMember member
```